# Can absolute divs feature in responsive design

Tags: html, absolute, image-scaling, responsive-design

I have started to design a photography website and I have included an absolute positioned logo in the top left hand corner. The area is made up of an absolute positioned div and an image within the div.

I was wondering whether I could make that absolute positioned div and logo, scale down depending on the screen size.

Is there anyone who can help? Here is the link so you can see what I am dealing with:

http://www.photographybytaraandclaire.com/newsite/index.html

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with responsive design you should work with percentages.

If you want to calculate what percentage width your logo should have you can use.

```
Logo width / Wrapper width * 100
```

The wrapper width is the width of you wrapper in your design and not the full page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try giving image width as percentage and no height to keep aspect/ratio.

```
<img src="..." style="width:15%" />
```